# Inserting multiple rows into an Excel Sheet with Vb.Net Com Add-In

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010, excel-addins

After determining a row index for an Excel Worksheet, InsertRow, I would like to insert 16 rows after it using VB.net.  I am building a COM add-in if that changes anything.  In VBA I would do this via:

```
 ...
 Dim InsertRow as String
 ...
 Dim ContractForm As Worksheet
 Set ContractForm = Sheets("Lab Contracts")
   ContractForm.Select
   ContractForm.Rows(InsertRow & ":" & InsertRow).Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(8, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this in VB.net.  I've tried:
[for all instances of (InsertRow ":" InsertRow) I've also tried ("47:47") and (InsertRow) in case that's not the correct syntax (vice versa).

```
  ...
  ContractSheet.Rows(InsertRow ":" InsertRow).Select()
  ContractSheet.Rows.Insert()
  ...
```

and
      ContractSheet.Rows("47:47").Select()
      ContractSheet.Range("47:47").EntireRow.Insert()
and
      ContractSheet.Rows(InsertRow).Select()
      For n = 1 To 16
         ContractSheet.Range(InsertRow & ":" & InsertRow).rows.insert(xlDown)
      Next
and
      ContractSheet.Rows(InsertRow).Select()
      For n = 1 To 16
         ContractSheet.Selection.Insert()
      Next

and I could go on, but I don't think it would be helpful (as I've always been trying for more than an hour on one issue before asking here).  Depending on how it goes I get one of the following errors:

HResult: 0x800A03EC; or

HResult 0x80020005; or

Cannot sift Objects off sheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to [avoid Select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/293078) unless you have to and you don't have to here. So, just to re-lay the groundwork, in VBA you should do:

```
Sub test()
Dim InsertRow As Long
Dim ContractForm As Worksheet

InsertRow = "5"
Set ContractForm = Sheets("Lab Contracts")
ContractForm.Rows(InsertRow).Resize(8).Insert xlShiftDown
End Sub
```

In VB.Net it's almost the same. (And I guess the xlShiftDown argument is unneeded in either VB or VBA):

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Sub test()
    Dim ContractForm As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim InsertRow As Int32

    ContractForm = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Lab Contracts")
    InsertRow = 5
    ContractForm.Rows(InsertRow).Resize(8).insert() '(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown)
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much!  I google around and was reading up on Rows on MSDN, and somehow never saw Resize.  I don't know how I missed that one.  I had figgured out from my own trial and error to avoid select, I just didn't know it was possible in this case.